# Kill a cron job from cron

Tags: cron, kill

I want to start the ubuntu update at night because internet is free at that time. and then kill the process in order to ensure that it does not download anything after 7:00 AM.

Is there any way to know the process ID of the cron job in order to kill it before the process run?
Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are just doing an apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, you can do this

```
sudo crontab -e
1 0 * * * apt-get update;apt-get -y upgrade
6 58 * * * pkill -9 apt-get
```

Comment: Your second cronjob is incorrect, it should be `58 6 * * *`. The first field is minutes, and the second is hours.

Comment: How can it be done as the task is running? (Killing a running cron process manually?)