# How can I see/stop current running crontab tasks?

Tags: cron, wget

1. How can I see crontab tasks which are in progress?
2. How can I **stop** crontab tasks which are in progress, manually?

> Is [this] question about see the current running cron processes?

Yes

> To kill a process manually one way is to use pkill

I had thought about pkill/killall, but some of my commands in crontab file are respectively! it means that after finishing a command, the next one will be started! for example:

```
sudo crontab -e
00 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget LINK ; shutdown -h now
```

So, If I kill `wget`, the computer will be powered off!!! -> I want to kill a cron task fully, not a part of it!

The next `pkill` problem: What about scripts? (I've imported some bash scripts to `crontab -e`) --> `sudo pkill ???`

Comment: Is your question about see the current running cron processes? or the list of cron-jobs?
Please edit your question to be more clear about this.
To stop the running cron-job go (http://askubuntu.com/q/272419/66980)

Comment: Edited; 
1. yes, watching current running cron processes? (I want to bring processes to foreground); 2. Then, I want to stop it manually?! (not from crontab schedule)

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Firstly, use only one command per line in crontab. Change this crontab line:

```
00 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget LINK ; shutdown -h now
```

so it looks like:

```
00 10 * * * /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
```

and create `/path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/wget LINK
shutdown -h now
```

Of course, don't forget to give it execution permission:

```
chmod +x /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
```

---

Secondly, you can see running crontab tasks, in a useful and readable format, in the output of:

```
ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep -A20 "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
```

They will appear in the first lines, something like this:

```
1108  1108 cron
4288  1108 \_ CRON
4289  4289     \_ /bin/sh -c /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
4290  4289         \_ /bin/bash /path/to/my/crontab/script1.sh
4295  4289             \_ /usr/bin/wget LINK
```

First column is PID, second is Session ID and third is the command started by cron. You can kill all the processes related to a specific cron task using the Session ID, so in the example above you should kill Session ID 4289:

```
pkill -s 4289
```

Comment: I get the this when running the "running crontab tasks" command:
```sh
ps: cmd: keyword not found
ps: illegal argument: afx
```

Comment: so cron doesn't give an "handy" way for show his processes?

Comment: @alecrust: Try this `ps -o pid,sess,cmd -afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"`

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process manually one way is to use `pkill`. pkill will stop all processes that have the following pattern in its name. for example to stop all wget processes use:

```
sudo pkill wget
```

Comment: I had thought about pkill/killall, but some of my commands in crontab file are respectively! it means that after finishing a command, the next one will be started! for example: `sudo crontab -e` => `00 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget LINK ; shutdown -h now` => So, If I kill **wget**, the computer will be powered off!!! -> I want to kill a cron task fully, not a part of it! the next pkill problem: What about scripts? (I've imported some bash scripts to `crontab -e`) - > `sudo pkill ???`

Answer (score 0):

change your cronjob like this

```
00 10 * * * /usr/bin/wget LINK && shutdown -h now
```

This should work, because the `&&` means that the second command only gets executed, when the first one was finished correctly (returning status 0 to the console/system), which shouldn't be the case (because the process got killed by the user and it should return another value then 0).