# crontab -e does not open the crontab for this user

Tags: command-line, cron

I had set up a few jobs using `crontab` a few months back and they had been working well up until a few days ago, I noticed one had not run. I just tried to check the crontab file using the user that created the jobs, using `crontab -e`, and no file opens. Terminal quickly flitts tosome screen and then back to the screen where I had entered the command. It goes and comes back too quickly for me to see what is there.

I have (as sudo) checked under `/var/spool/cron/crontab/` and see there is a file for the mentioned user, which contains the basic:

```
> DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
> (- installed on Wed Mar 21 00:12:22 2018)
> (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
```

I notice that the isntall date is pretty much exactly where my cron jobs stopped! Maybe the system needed a restart for some reason...

I restarted the machine and again tried: `crontab -e`, this time I got the following error coming from `Emacs` (the default editor, I believe):

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".

Warning: due to a long standing Gtk+ bug
http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715

.... [truncated]
```

So I changed the default editor to `nano`:

```
user@user:~$ select-editor 

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/code
  4. /usr/bin/emacs24
  5. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-5 [2]: 2
```

... and tried again:

```
user@user:~$ crontab -e
```

This just gave the same problem as initially described - it shortly seemed to open a file then close it again.

Is there another way to debug and (hopefully) get back the original crontab file? The jobs were quit complex to set up (see note #2 below)   :-/

I tried to find running crontab tasks using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313033/how-can-i-see-stop-current-running-crontab-tasks?rq=1), so cron is running, but what about my crontab tasks?

```
user@user:~$  ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
1077  1077 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

#### Other notes:

- anacron is installed
- the cron jobs themselves are defined in the crontab file, not via external scripts
- one cronjob used a virtual env, which does still exist and works and I can execute the job manually

#### Updates:

The output from some further checks (mostly requested by @steeldriver)

```
user@user:~$ ls -l $(which crontab)
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 36080 Apr  5  2016 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Is that the `setuid` **s** in there? I compared it to `ping`, because I read that should have some kind of elevated permissions:

```
user@user:~$ ls -l $(which ping)
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 Mai  7  2014 /bin/ping
```

Running `crontab` as sudo:

```
user@user:~$ sudo crontab -e
[sudo] password for user: 
no crontab for root - using an empty one
No modification made
```

Trying the desired command as sudo, using the user's setup:

```
user@user:~$ sudo -H -u user bash -c 'crontab -e'
No modification made
```

Checking if permissions for the entire spool are as expected:

```
user@user:~$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root 36864 Apr  1 14:22 /tmp
user@user:~$ sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER
f: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxr-xr-x root    root    var
drwxr-xr-x root    root    spool
drwxr-xr-x root    root    cron
drwx-wx--T root    crontab crontabs
-rw------- user    crontab user
```

Comment: I'm curious what happens with `crontab -l`?

Comment: @steeldriver - Nothing comes back at all! (Not a good sign, I know) Assuming the worst - the crontab file was removed somehow - how can we explain that `crontab -e` doesn't let me at least start a new file?

Comment: I'd check the permissions of the crontab binary e.g. `ls -l $(which crontab)` - does it have its SETUID bit? is the temporary directory writable and sticky (`ls -ld /tmp`)? Are the spool permissions correct all the way down (`sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`)?

Comment: also does root's work (`sudo crontab -e`). AFAIK the default editor is`nano` (or possibly even `ed`) - I don't think emacs is even installed in the vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: @steeldriver - please see the updated info in the post  :)

Comment: Hmm... I don't see anything wrong there (apart from the fact that you have apparently lost your orginal crontab content of course). It's not something silly like an alias or shell function is it? have you checked `type crontab`? What happens if you set the editor explicitly like `EDITOR=/bin/nano crontab -e`?

Comment: @steeldriver - You're right - the only problem is that I still cannot open up crontab a user all (only sudo). `type crontab` gives: `crontab is /usr/bin/crontab`. Setting the editor gives the same result as without doing it; a quick 'open/close' of something. A single point (period) if left on the terminal line after the 'close'. I have tried using another terminal emulator - same problem.

Comment: Weird thought... What if there is a bad hex code in the file causing `nano` to throw up? If you use `sudo cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER` does the file display as it should?... Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - thanks anyway - unfortunately I know this won't work, because I noticed that there is no file there to be opened.

Comment: @DexterMorgan Maybe you would have better luck if you copied a working file there first?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  @steeldriver - As root I could run `crontab -e`. Using the template, I manually added a file for the user and it runs, but I still cannot open/edit it **as** the user, i.e. using `crontab -e`. Also `crontab -l` still doesn't return anything. Could you please tell me the correct user group for the crontab file? From sudo's generated file I could see the owner should be `crontab`, but can't find a standard example online anywhere.

Comment: @DexterMorgan To create a new cron setup, signon as the user and use `crontab -e`. Don't copy files manually from sudo. The group should be `crontab` according to files on my system. What does `sudo ll /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER` reveal? It should say owner `user` and group `crontab`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - using `crontab -e` was exactly the problem from the beginning - it didn't do anything. It turns out the Emacs setup was the cause. Even following @steeldriver 's advice of trying `EDITOR=/bin/nano crontab -e` was not working. I recorded a screencast and stopped on the frame where a file quickly opens - it was Emacs' splash screen. There were settings in `~/.profile`, which caused the Emacs daemon to hijack calls to an editor. After removing those setting and restarting, `crontab -e` as the user worked. The original crontab was lost. Still don't understand how that happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Just to post the outcome and perhaps help someone who sees the same thing - this is a summary of the comments below my original question

Using `crontab -e` was the start of the problem - it didn't do anything.

It turns out the Emacs setup was the cause (but I assume any other editor could somehow cause this problem).

Following @steeldriver 's advice of trying `EDITOR=/bin/nano crontab -e` (trying to force crontab to use **nano** did not help.

I recorded a screen-cast and stopped on the frame where a file quickly opens - it was Emacs' splash screen.

There were settings in `~/.profile`, which caused the Emacs daemon to hijack calls to an editor. After removing those setting and restarting, `crontab -e` as the user worked.

The settings seemed to be an incorrectly copy-pasted version of this (found on the Emacs wiki):

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"                  # $EDITOR should open in terminal
export VISUAL="emacsclient -c -a emacs"         # $VISUAL opens in GUI with non-daemon as alternate
```

[I don't remember where the actual mistake was]

The original crontab file was lost. I still don't understand how that happened

Comment: If somebody has a more general solution to finding out the root cause of something like this, I will accept that answer!